# Admin page redirect to another admin page

Tags: admin, redirect

How can I redirect certain WordPress admin pages to another admin page.

For example I never want a user to see `wp-admin/about.php` it should always redirect to `wp-admin/index.php`.

There are also a couple plugins that redirect to a plugin welcome page with promotions the I want to be able to check if this URL then redirect to this URL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`get_current_screen()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_current_screen) to check on which page you are then make a redirect to specific admin page.

`get_current_screen()` return the screen object like

```
WP_Screen Object
(
    [action] => 
    [base] => dashboard
    [columns:WP_Screen:private] => 0
    [id] => dashboard
    [in_admin:protected] => site
    [is_network] => 
    [is_user] => 
    [parent_base] => 
    [parent_file] => 
    [post_type] => 
    [taxonomy] => 
    [_help_tabs:WP_Screen:private] => Array
        (
        )

    [_help_sidebar:WP_Screen:private] => 
    [_screen_reader_content:WP_Screen:private] => Array
        (
        )

    [_options:WP_Screen:private] => Array
        (
        )

    [_show_screen_options:WP_Screen:private] => 
    [_screen_settings:WP_Screen:private] => 
)
```

You can use `base` key to identify the page base!

Example:-

```
add_action('current_screen', 'wpse_225416_redirect_admin_page');
/**
 * Redirect specific admin page
 */
function wpse_225416_redirect_admin_page() {
    $my_current_screen = get_current_screen();
    if (isset($my_current_screen->base) && $my_current_screen->base == 'about') {
        wp_redirect(admin_url());
        exit();
    }
}
```

Use `current_screen` hook because before that `get_current_screen()` will return nothing.

Comment: So, if i need it to redirect back to the dashboard it should look like this?
function wpse_225416_redirect_admin_page() {
    $my_current_screen = get_current_screen();
    if (isset($my_current_screen->base) && $my_current_screen->base == 'about') {
        wp_redirect(admin_url('index'));
        exit();
    }
}

Comment: The current code in answer redirecting `about.php` to `index.php`! No need to add index in admin url `admin_url('index')` for dashboard.

Comment: I've added the code above from the example, but I am still able to get to the about page.

Comment: I've tested it and it is working fine. Please debug, clear the cache, disable plugins and switch to default theme. It is hard to say why it does not work in your system, because it is very basic and working example.

Comment: Question, if I need to redirect from this page: edit.php?post_type=newsletter&page=mymail_welcome

to the dashboard, how should it be written?

Comment: check for `base` `edit.php` along with `isset()` for `post_type` == `'newsletter'` and same for `page` and `mymail_welcome`

Comment: So this is what I have, but didn't work.

    add_action('current_screen', 'wpse_225416_redirect_admin_page');
    function wpse_225416_redirect_admin_page() {$my_current_screen = get_current_screen();
    if (isset($my_current_screen->base) && $my_current_screen->base == 'edit.php' && post_type == 'newsletter' && page == 'mymail_welcome') {
        wp_redirect(admin_url());
        exit();
    }
}